# jquery editable edit link?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery and the editable plugin.

Works ace and we're very happy.

However, my boss wants a link/div just to the side of the editable div saying edit.
Clicking that will pop up the editable field.

I've used:

```
$('#my_edit_button_id').click(function() {
  $('.my_editable_div').focus();
});
$('.my_editable_div').editable(/* my settings */);

<div class="my_editable_div"></div>
<div id="my_edit_button_id">Edit info</div>
```

class my_editable_div works great on its own.. but focus is not focusing the mouse.

Anyone come across this before?
I'll continue to scour the jQuery docs...

Comment: Can you provide a link to your *editable* plugin so we'll refer to the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the best way to do this would be to trigger the `click` handlers on the `div` itself, since it seems to be clicking on the editable element that causes it to change and to receive focus:

```
$('#my_edit_button_id').click(function() {
  $('.my_editable_div').click();
});
$('.my_editable_div').editable(/* my settings */);
```

NB that I'm not familiar with this plugin -- it's just a reasoned guess based on the [docs](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why not using this plugin? easy and flexible using **data-** attribute technique https://github.com/tectual/jQuery-Editable more samples available at [jquery editable](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/7/jQuery-Editable-Plugin-Best-In-Place-Editor-.html)

Using it you can call "**click**" event of the editable once clicking the edit icon. or use it's **data-for** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `div` tags cannot have a focus, even if they're content editable.

Sorry, my bad. Just found out that you can do it, but you need to set the `tabindex attribute. Try this:

`$("#my_editable_div").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();`

Comment: they can, you just need to specify tabindex property

Answer (score 0):

by default div doesn't buble focus event, so you need to either change `div` to `a` tag or add `tabindex` attribute

the other story is that editable plugin change DOM on click , so you need to find form and input box after click , and fire focus event on it, not on div